# How can I format a time variable to include colons? (JDE Event Rules)

Tags: jde

I'm trying to create an ER that adds colons to my time variable in JDE (OMW). I've tried using the substring function to make 3 substrings and then add a colon inbetween each substring, but that doesn't seem to be working for some reason.

Here is what I tried to do as a test to see if the substring would work.

`substr([PC Time - Last Updated (F0911) (UPMT)],0,2 )`

This should cut my time from an 8 digit number to a 2 digit number, but it doesn't seem to be doing anything. Any ideas? Currently this line of code is in the DO section of my event rules.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want using the substr function. But you will have to give the function your time. From your code, i can see you used a "PC" variable.

```
substr([PC Time - Last Updated (F0911) (UPMT)],0,2 )
```

Which relate to the previous value inside the business view. Maybe you wanted to use a "BC" one? Because the first record will always be null for a "PC" variable Inside a DO SECTION event rule. Just make sure you are sending a value to the substr function.